# Getting data by string column names in Entity Framework(Not duplicate they are exactly different question)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with C#. And I want to getting columns with string column name like below. How can I achieve this?

**I want like below**

```
context.Students.Select({
"Name",
"Surname",
"Number",
"BirthDate",
}).ToList();
```

**Please don't advice below solution**

```
context.Students.Select(p=> new {
p.Name,
p.Surname,
p.Number,
p.BirthDate,
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it with strings literals? When something goes wrong it's harder to find what, and when you change something they won't throw compiler errors like the second solution will.

Comment: (Sorry. I gave wrong link. This link is true.) My main aim is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553305/exclude-columns-getting-data-with-entity-framework , but I quess that it is not possible.So I think this solution. I will get all property of model and erase some colums from list. @MindSwipe

Comment: Everything is possible with enough time and knowledge, I'm just saying it doesn't make sense/ is dangerous to use string literals instead of `p => new { p.Name ...}`

Comment: I found the solution by creatiing class with these properties. And then I used `ProjectTo` method of `AutoMapper`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558512/getting-only-some-columns-in-dto-class-from-table-by-entity-framework  and  http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported out of the box.

You can use `context.Students.SqlQuery` but then you will need to pass a complete SQL Statement.

Alternatively you may need to create some helper that maps string to properties, but that will involve reflection.

Comment: SqlQuery maybe a solution. But, my main aim is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553305/exclude-columns-getting-data-with-entity-framework. So, I will take columns names automatically and will create query. But, I hope, I can find  better way from SqlQuey. Because, it's very difficult create dinamically `where` filter with sql query @Nick