# Getting only some columns in DTO class from table by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with C#. I have a Student table in my database and it has **30 columns**. And I want to getting only some columns of table which are in DTO class **without writing property names** like below. How can I achieve this?

My DTO class:

```
public class StudentDTO()
{
    public long Name{ get; set; }
    public long Surname{ get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }
    public int StudentNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
context.Students.Select(p=> new StudentDTO
{
  ????? StudentDTO.AllProperties  ?????
}).ToList();
```

Please don't advice below solution, because this is not what I'm looking for.

```
context.Students.Select(p => new 
                             {
                                 p.Name,
                                 p.Surname,
                                 p.BirthDate,
                                 p.StudentNumber
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: You already asked this question 2 times. This is third...

Comment: No. This is very different from them. @FCin That question with string property name. But in this question, I have another class and I will map. So, It is not same. I think, you see the class name and said they are the same.

Comment: Are Students DbSet's type and StduentDTO are different types, right? What's wrong with the linq select? You might be looking for [AutoMapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html)?

Comment: I don't want write property names(Name,Surname,BirthDate,StudentNumber) while getting data from database. AutoMapper synchoronize two classes after got data from database. But, I want in query in other words before get data from database @ibubi

Comment: @HasanOzdemir It **is** in fact possible: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDerck . This is what I was looking for `ProjectTo` method of AutoMapper. I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from comment of @AlexanderDerck. `ProjectTo` method of `AutoMapper` solve my problem. [docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: If you write, ı will remove my answer and I will mark yours as an answer. I wrote because of I can't mark the comment. @AlexanderDerck

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Automapper? As long as the names of the properties in your DTO match the ones in the EF context, you're good to do. And as you add properties to your DTO, they would automatically be translated.

If the names/types don't match between the DTO and EF context, there may need to be additional configuration in your mapper profile.

Here is a simplified example.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
        var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

        var fullStudent = new FullStudent()
        {
            Name = "Mike",
            Surname = "Magoo",
            BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
            StudentNumber = 1,
            Grade = "Freshman",
            PhoneNumber = "555-5555"
        };

        var limitedStudent = mapper.Map<StudentDTO>(fullStudent);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class FullStudent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int StudentNumber { get; set; }

    public string Grade { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int StudentNumber { get; set; }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<FullStudent, StudentDTO>();
    }
}
```

Automapper can be installed as a nuget package.

Comment: This usage of AutoMapper is: synchoronize two classes after got data from database. But, I want in query in other words before get data from database. @AlexanderDerck ' s solution is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You should use `ProjectTo`, that restricts the queried properties to the ones in the DTO.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold . Please remove my duplicate. Because that question is not duplicate.