# Entity Framework - Include Properties, but exclude single columns

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Let's say I have a list of items, which each can reference a list of documents (and other stuff).
In `Entity Framework` I can get the list like that:

```
var items = context.Items
        .Include(i => i.Documents)
        .Include(i => i.OtherProperty)
        .ToList()
```

Now this includes all columns from documents. Is it possible to exclude one of these columns (eg. the "Data"-column which stores the complete document as binary)? 
Something like this:

```
var items = context.Items
        .Include(i => i.Documents)
            .ButExclude(d => d.Data)
        .Include(i => i.OtherProperty)
        .ToList()
```

I know that I could use .Select() and create an object without the data property, but since I use a lot of foreign keys I would rather like to use includes. 
I also know that it is better to separate the document's metadata from the actual content, but well... I haven't...

Comment: What about creating a 2nd entity for the same table and mapping the `Data` as `Ignore`? I would make sure any relationships are unidirectional on one of the 2 entities for that table.

Comment: Use Automapper or mapster or somthing else with DTO?

Answer (score 0):

Make another model that doesnt include data that you dont need

```
public class CreateAndUpdatePropertiesModel
{
    public string Documents { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperties { get; set; }
}
```

And then use this model as a property in primary model:

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public string Documents { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperties { get; set; }

    // And then add the CreateAndUpdateProperties model as a property
    public CreateAndUpdateProperties { get; set; }
}
```

then only Include wanted data
`.Include(s => s.CreateAndUpdateProperties)`

This Question was previously asked many times:

[Exclude columns getting data with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553305/exclude-columns-getting-data-with-entity-framework)

- Added as answer due to low amount of rep(cant comment)